# Newcomers vs early overflowers

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I know a user whose latest question is from mid 2012 and latest answer is from late 2012.

In the last several years this user collected over 20k points. While this is great for him, I think it's unfair for new, active, users.

[image]

This situation resembles, a lot, property management in real life, where early investors accumulate wealth by having investments in the good neighbourhoods, close to CBD. 
Yes, there are new neighbourhoods and opportunities, but the benefits to reap are not as big.

Answers to early *C#* and/or *Git* questions are examples of golden geese.

I don't see this as good for the Stack Overflow community as it biased towards early adopters of the site.

A cap of amount of upvotes on a question/answer (or points one gets from it) would be good (or should be lowered if it already exists). Another option could be adding different number of points as the question/answer ages (or gets more popular).

---

Response to selected comments:

**Communism**

Progressive taxing is common across the world and generally considered fair.

As for caps, there already is a cap of 200 reputation per day, so I'm not inventing anything really new here.

**Jealousy**

No jealousy here. I neither have the skills nor time to be at the top.

**jezreal and coldspeed**

jezreal and especially coldspeed are excellent examples. Thank you for that.

These users illustrate my point very well. These users work hard and they're great for the community, but they have to fight *harder* than people who were here when `git commit -a` type questions were being asked.

**You can get high rep**

"There is 0 evidence that new users can't gain reputation."

I don't argue that you cannot get into 100k points. This is not the point I'm making, and I'm sorry if it isn't clear.

My point is that it is *progressively harder* to as Stack Exchange is getting *older*.

**Do you really attach such a high value to a steadily incrementing number?**

Yes and no. It's not really about attaching value. It think it makes it for better community if the return on investment was limited or diminishing over time (or popularity).

---

Thanks for your comments!

I suspect this will have to be reassessed at some point in the future. It may just be a bit too early now ;) No worries.

Comment: Yay communism!!!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059

Comment: What problem does this cause? Why is it problematic that those users have high rep?

Comment: Just another way us oldies have shafted the next generation.  That's neoliberalism for you.

Comment: Do you really attach such a high value to a steadily incrementing number?

Comment: @Mat The only problem this cause is the OP being frustrated by the fact they don't have high rep like other users. It's called jealousy (I think...)

Comment: Votes are not a finite resource. Someone else getting some votes over time does **not** mean other people don't get those votes; the vast majority of our users never hit their voting limits.

Comment: There is 0 evidence that new users can't gain reputation. [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) became really active in January of last year: https://stackexchange.com/users/3465245/jezrael?tab=reputation and is doing just fine.

Comment: Another example, [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) kicked into [high gear in June this year](https://stackexchange.com/users/6321039/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85?tab=reputation).

Comment: If users only could resist the urge to find these old posts useful ...

Comment: Put simply, if you try and have the ability, you can still reach a giant ton of reputation very quickly. Some new people are even averaging substantially above 200 rep a day from bounties and accepts.

Comment: The property owner simile doesn't really hold water - with property, you have income that is not directly related to what you work with your own hands. Rep from answers is always in return for your own work, however long ago.

Comment: But either way, there's a lot of people who agree with you to some degree. There have been many many suggestions on how to fix this over the years. [Jon Skeet himself once proposed a per-question cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again) which would directly address the issue you're talking about! But read [Kevin's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136293/138112) in that question to see what that would do to the "poor."

Comment: Hmm, this is all relative.  A billionaire isn't going to get very excited when he trips over a suitcase filled with a million dollars.  If you find a user with high rep then you'll likely find somebody that got bored with the grind and the gawdawful Interesting page.  Keeping it relative is already strongly encouraged by SO, the user pages rank by week, quarter and year.  Use those to compare yourself.

Comment: There will be other opportunities for gold rushes besides Git. Actually, there are smaller ones in my home tags every year after Apple's WWDC, and I imagine the same is true for other platforms.

Comment: What is **CBD**?

Comment: You can't really prove that a post posted today can't get to the same popularity/usefulness that some of those older posts have. It's certainly possible for that to occur, just not with the topics that it has already occurred for. These users getting rep for something they did in the past doesn't hinder you or anyone else from gaining the same amount of daily rep if not more. I don't see the problem. This isn't a common occurance and i don't think we need some rule or tool in place to deal with 56,657 cases out of 14 million (questions with 50 or more, or 149 if you look at 2k or more)

Answer (score 16):

I must ask ... what are you missing by the sheer fact that other people have more reputation then you do?

What, specifically, are they denying to you by having that reputation? Rep points aren't a zero sum game on Stack Overflow. Every time a post is upvoted or accepted, or every time someone gets an edit approved, new reputation is created for that user.

The fact that Jon Skeet has >900k reputation doesn't have any bearing whatsoever on your next 10 or 15.

You could argue that people have a vote limit and thus reputation isn't infinite after all, but that'd be silly. Few people actually use their votes to the limit every day, and the cap resets daily anyways.

This isn't real life economics, we're not competing for limited resources.

Comment: 1. "We're not competing for limited resources." - I'm arguing the opposite.

Comment: 2. JonSkeet is not my example. Please refer to the example I have given.

Comment: @mayu I don't see you arguing for anything, just proposing various caps. New highly popular answers still get posted all the time. There are new users earning tons of reputation

Comment: @magisch true and those people really have to work for it, while this person amassed their "fortune" while not even being active on the site. I can sort of relate how this may seem unfair, but at the same time you're still free to do exactly the same yourself today - post a popular question/answer and then go away for a few years while your content keeps on collecting upvotes. Perfectly fair.

Comment: I wouldn't even argue this as a problem. If your answer is so good it attracs many upvotes even a year or so after its posting, it's arguably deserved anyways.

Comment: @mayu What is the limited resource we're competing for, then?

Answer (score 10):

You already have a cap of a maximum of 200 reputation per day (excluding earned bounties).

Reputation is a vague form to measure how much a person is contributing positive to the community. Of course it is not perfect (High/Low-Traffic tags), but it is the best what we have.

I don't think it is unfair, that an early bird is earning much reputation, since this person must be helped many people to earn it. Reputation is only given, if a person mark a post helpful through upvote or a gives a bounty.

The best thing you can do, is contribute positive where you can.

See: [How to get initial reputation on Stack Overflow with the new-user restrictions in place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139661/how-to-get-initial-reputation-on-stack-overflow-with-the-new-user-restrictions-i)